# How can I elevate blaze, without using lava?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am making a dual-spawner blaze farm, and I need to elevate the blaze, so I don't get out of the 16-block range of both spawners.

I am using Nim's design for gathering the blaze into a tunnel, and have a handy slimeblock pusher to make them go through the corridors, but i want to elevate them some 10 blocks to bring them into the kill chamber, having that kill chamber in a convenient place.

How can I elevate the blaze using redstone/slime?

Answer (score 1):

1. **Minecarts**: Put the blazes in minecarts by moving the minecarts past the blazes, redirect the minecart where you want it to be and let it run over a activator rail which will eject the blaze (or destroy the minecart with a cactus). Be careful that blazes don't shoot and break the minecarts. *However, due to bugs introduced by 1.9 you may have problems getting the blazes into the minecart in the first place.*
2. **Slime blocks**: Have sticky pistons push slime blocks with the blaze(s) on top upwards. This will move the blazes several blocks vertically. To move them to the side horizontally so they don't fall (glide) down again, have pistons at the right place extending at the right time horizontally to push the blazes over. May be easier to use sticky pistons with slime blocks here as well. *However, again due to 1.9 bugs you may have problems accelerating entities with slime blocks when they aren't standing still.*
3. ( **Use AI**: Make sure there is a line of sight between you can the blazes. They will get aggressive towards you and often try to hover upwards. ) *May not work due to an aggrevated blaze making other blazes in the area aggressive and therefore making them float upwards as well, which would mess negatively with the blazes in the spawner (expect if you would use a method to let the blazes float out of the spawning region).*
4. **Piston translocator**: Use a vertical piston translocator to move blazes upwards and/or to the side. This abuses the behaviour of normal pistons that will pull an entity through the piston block in the direction of the retracting piston head if the piston head intersects the entity before retracting. (This is the same as posted by Uchiha Madara.) *However, this is based on a - once again - 1.9-introduced bug, that may get fixed in the future (guess why...).*

Comment: #1 and #3 are invalid since question specific asks for redstone + slime. #3 would be catastrophic sinc blaze AI causes all blaze in range to fly, breaking the spawner farm. #1 is impractical due to bugs also.

Comment: Do you have a schematic for a piston-mob elevator? Since blaze does not take fall damage and float, i think it is slightly different than a player one.

Comment: @Mindwin What do you mean with "piston-mob elevator"? A slime block pushing elevator shouldn't really work differently. Blazes still get propelled several blocks into the air, even though they will start to float down instantly again, so need to be pushed horizontally in time (or a another slime block pushing piston moved in underneath the blaze in time). If you mean a translocator elevator, there shouldn't be a difference between blazes and other entities. You are definitely right on #3, didn't know that.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the [Minecraft 1.10 piston glitch](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2qdVLq0fzaI)

Comment: Glitches also may be fixed in future updates, so they are not the best option when using redstone/command blocks.